# Error compiling code for creating boost.log format

Tags: c++, boost, boost-log, boost-logging

I am trying to compile following code with gcc 7.3.0 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with option -std=c++14:

```
auto createLogFormatter()
{
    boost::log::expressions::stream_type stream;
    stream  << boost::log::expressions::format_date_time<boost::posix_time::ptime>("TimeStamp", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S  ")
            << boost::log::expressions::attr<int>("Severity")
            << " " // ERROR HERE
            << boost::log::expressions::attr<boost::log::attributes::current_thread_id::value_type>("ThreadID")
            << " "
            << boost::log::expressions::smessage;
    return stream;
}
```

And getting strange error:

```
Log.cpp:51:13: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘boost::log::v2_mt_posix::expressions::aux::make_output_actor<boost::phoenix::actor<boost::log::v2_mt_posix::expressions::aux::attribute_output_terminal<boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::phoenix::argument<2> >, 0> >, boost::posix_time::ptime, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::fallback_to_none, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::aux::light_function<void(boost::log::v2_mt_posix::basic_formatting_ostream<char>&, const boost::posix_time::ptime&)> > >, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::expressions::attribute_actor<int, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::fallback_to_none, void, boost::phoenix::actor>, int, false>::type {aka boost::phoenix::actor<boost::log::v2_mt_posix::expressions::aux::attribute_output_terminal<boost::phoenix::actor<boost::log::v2_mt_posix::expressions::aux::attribute_output_terminal<boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::phoenix::argument<2> >, 0> >, boost::posix_time::ptime, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::fallback_to_none, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::aux::light_function<void(boost::log::v2_mt_posix::basic_formatting_ostream<char>&, const boost::posix_time::ptime&)> > >, int, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::fallback_to_none, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::to_log_fun<void> > >}’ and ‘const char [2]’)
     stream  << boost::log::expressions::format_date_time<boost::posix_time::ptime>("TimeStamp", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S  ")
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
             << boost::log::expressions::attr<int>("Severity")
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
             << " "
             ^~~~~~
```

According to Boost examples [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/log/doc/html/log/tutorial/formatters.html), such thing should work:

```
    expr::stream
        << expr::attr< unsigned int >("LineID")
        << ": <" << logging::trivial::severity
        << "> " << expr::smessage
```

But I am getting such error. 
What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler error is likely caused by a missing include. Lambda expression operators are provided by Boost.Phoenix in `boost/phoenix/operator.hpp`. Or you can just include `boost/log/expressions.hpp`, which provides all Boost.Log expression nodes as well as operators.

But besides that, your `createLogFormatter` function is incorrect as it discards the whole formatter expression. You should not be creating and returning a `stream` object, it is only a terminal that starts the formatter expression. You need to return the function object that is created as a result of the lambda expression.

```
auto createLogFormatter()
{
    auto fmt = stream  << boost::log::expressions::format_date_time<boost::posix_time::ptime>("TimeStamp", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S  ")
            << boost::log::expressions::attr<int>("Severity")
            << " " // ERROR HERE
            << boost::log::expressions::attr<boost::log::attributes::current_thread_id::value_type>("ThreadID")
            << " "
            << boost::log::expressions::smessage;
    return fmt;
}
```

If you want to have a stable return type, you can use `boost::log::formatter` to wrap the expression.

Comment: Thank you, Andrey!